# Why is this simple join taking so long?

Tags: mysql, performance, innodb, myisam

I'm trying to run some reporting queries on a MySQL database, and I'm running into serious performance issues for some reason. One table, `page_views`, is extremely large (~70 million records), so some slowness is to be expected, but it's got lots of indexing, and all the queries are restricted to a certain date range on the `started_at` field. I'm seeing simple joins taking upwards of ten minutes. The query I've been tossing around lately (which I've stripped way down) looks like this:

```
select count(page_views.id) as views
from playpack_media
join page_views on page_views.itemId=playpack_media.media_Id
where playpack_media.playpack_id = 1
    and page_views.started_at BETWEEN '2014-06-23' and '2014-07-07'
```

It's taking about 11 minutes 30 seconds to run. `DESCRIBE` returns this analysis:

```
| id | select_type | table          | type | possible_keys        | key         | key_len | ref                                 | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+----------------+------+----------------------+-------------+---------+-------------------------------------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | playpack_media | ref  | media_id,playpack_id | playpack_id | 4       | const                               |  594 |             |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | page_views     | ref  | itemId,started_at    | itemId      | 4       | db_playsmrt.playpack_media.media_id | 4236 | Using where |
```

It seems to bottleneck at the "copying to tmp table" stage. I've tried increasing tmp_table_size and max_heap_table_size to 256M and key_buffer_size to 64M - the latter change dropped the time from ~18 minutes to ~11, which is a big improvement but still terrible, and a further increase to 128M didn't do much.

One thing I noticed while hammmering at this is that `page_views` uses MyISAM and `playpack_media` uses InnoDB, which I'm reading can be an issue. However, changing `page_views` to InnoDB on my (much smaller) development server makes it dramatically slower. It's possible that it becomes worthwhile on larger tables, but just making the experiment would take a long time.

Does anyone have an idea what's going on here? What else should I be looking at?

Comment: You say it has "lot's of indexes".  But, does it specifically have an index on just page_views.itemId and playpack_media.media_Id?  How about page_views.started_at?  I'm not a MySQL guy, so I don't know how to interpret the DESCRIBE result.

Comment: Yes, all three fields are indexed. There's no compound indexes on them, though, if that's what you had in mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the original query

```
select count(page_views.id) as views
from playpack_media
join page_views on page_views.itemId=playpack_media.media_Id
where playpack_media.playpack_id = 1
    and page_views.started_at BETWEEN '2014-06-23' and '2014-07-07'
```

You should do a couple of things.

First, create to compound indexes

```
ALTER TABLE page_views     ADD INDEX started_at_itemid_ndx    (started_at,itemid);
ALTER TABLE playpack_media ADD INDEX playpack_id_media_Id_ndx (playpack_id,media_Id)
```

Try to refactor the query

```
SELECT COUNT(1) as views FROM
(
    SELECT media_Id FROM playpack_media
    WHERE playpack_id = 1
) A INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT itemId FROM page_views WHERE
    started_at BETWEEN '2014-06-23' and '2014-07-07'
) B ON A.media_Id = B.itemId;
```

Perhaps breaking down the views by ItemID

```
SELECT IFNULL(A.media_id,'Total') Media,COUNT(1) as views FROM
(
    SELECT media_Id FROM playpack_media
    WHERE playpack_id = 1
) A INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT itemId FROM page_views WHERE
    started_at BETWEEN '2014-06-23' and '2014-07-07'
) B ON A.media_Id = B.itemId
GROUP BY A.media_id WITH ROLLUP;
```

Comment: (started_at, item_id) will be useless, as a range scan is used on the first column.

Comment: @jynus you are right in general but the rewrite suggested by Rolando will most probably use the index to create the derived table subresult.

Comment: So, if I follow the logic here, you're using subqueries to force the database to crop out the unused part of each table separately using the indexes, and then it joins the derived tables without indexing? Or is there some kind of automatic indexing to speed that part up?

Comment: Yes. The idea is to gather as little data as possible before doing the join. I learned this trick from this video : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZVisY-fEoMw&playnext=1&list=PL0194B59719B45A96. It does not solve every kind of JOIN problem. Try it out anyway and see if it works for you.

Comment: This is working remarkably well, which is kind of odd, because all the optimization advice I've ever seen about subqueries amounts to "use joins instead wherever possible".

Comment: I would like to recommend a book to you : High Performance MySQL (3rd edition) (ISBN 978-1-449-31428-6). Read Pages 207-209 under heading "Ways to Restructure Queries". The three(3) sections under it are "Complex Queries Versus Many Queries", "Chopping Up a Query", and "Join Decomposition". This will give you more ideas for planning your queries.

Answer (score 1):

Single-column indexes may not be helpful enough and it requires a temporary table. In fact, they may be harmful as non-optimal indexes are being used with little information on why it is happening.

The best possible indexes are

```
(playpack_media.playpack_id, playpack_media.media_id) AND (page_views.itemId, pageviews.started_at)
```

or

```
(page_views.started_at) AND (playpack_media.media_Id, playpack_media.playpack_id)
```

, depending on the selectivity of your conditions.

**My bet is on the first option**, as I will assume that the range on `pageviews` by itself selects a lot of records. Please make sure to get rid of unused indexes by this or other queries, as they will sometimes harm more than they help, by **slowing down queries and confusing the query planner**.

For future reference, I recommend combining the `EXPLAIN` command with `FLUSH STATUS; <execute query>; SHOW SESSION STATUS like 'Hand%';` which will give you more detailed post-execution statistics.

Comment: Hmm. Unfortunately, the query I posted is just a concise example; the actual queries are much more complex. But I do see where you're going here, and I think I'll be able to apply it to the actual queries. I just wish the indexing wasn't going to shut things down for so long - last time I had to update page_views, the site was down for three hours while it reindexed.

Comment: You will love me :-) : http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.2/pt-online-schema-change.html